# PHPEXCEL export to pdf

Tags: php, pdf-generation, phpexcel, mpdf

Hi guys need your help,

I rather have stuck in the programming side of my php.

I'm using PHPExcel to convert to pdf, but I have realize that when I convert, the format is different, is there a way to convert to PDF using fixedasformat function like Vba to export to pdf...

I have use the 3 library that is in the documentation but each library render a different format.

I'm using PHPExcel 1.8. I try downgrade the version and uses the library but it does not help much.

really appreciate everyone help..

Comment: Why did you think that downgrading the versions would help?

Comment: In what way is the formatting wrong? PHPExcel builds HTML markup of the Excel spreadsheet, and then feeds that to the appropriate PDF renderer? Is the HTML markup wrong? If so, how? Details would help

Comment: it is out of alignment but if i export and saved as pdf it is okay.

Comment: Please provide details? What is out of alignment?

Comment: when i add a new row in excel when render into pdf, the new row is not obvious enough, i try to add new row to 3 to 5 but not able to do it. only exce able to do it. sorry for any inconvenience caused, for the fonts that i need i also could not get it render into pdf is there any way that i can render a custom font into pdf?

Comment: The PDF Writer has a `setFont()` method, allowing you to set a font name, but only the tcPDF Rendered honours it

Comment: Now i facing another issue is there any way to insert new row  instead of using  $sheet->insertNewRowBefore($counter_line++,1);

Comment: No, insertNewRowBefore() is the method defined for inserting a new row in the middle of existing rows

Comment: at least can you show some snippet of code? it is hard to answer without code ...